# Como modelar las siguientes entidades en una Base de datos relacional?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, uml

Tengo que crear en un DB tablas con las siguientes 3 entidades : `User(id,nombre), Client(id,nombre) y Atributo(id,Nombre,Valor)`.

La entidades estan relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

- User puede tener muchos clients (uno a muchos)
- Client puede tener solo un user (uno a uno)
- User y Client tienen muchos atributos

Mis preguntas son:

- Atributo deberia tener una relacion uno a uno o uno a muchos con los
  User/Client?
- Es necesario que cree otra tabla de Atributos para establecer
  correctamente las relaciones?
- Deberia crear 2 tablas separadas de Atributos: una para los User y
  otra para los Clients? o basta una sola?
- Como estarian estructuradas las tablas y cuales serian sus llaves
  externas que indican las relaziones?

Edit: Sorry don't speak english

Comment: Según por lo que entiendo, la ultima relación es una relación n:m, es decir, muchos a muchos, ahí tienes que crear una tabla intermedia si o si :D. En cuanto a las llaves foraneas, en una relación 1:1 cualquiera puede llevar la relación (FK) dependiendo el caso. En una relación n:1 o viceversa la llave foranea la lleva el que tiene n relaciones.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que un Atributo tiene muchos user/client ? Que parametros tendria esta tabla intermedia ?

Comment: Esta pregunta, esta basada en opiniones. con los nombres de las tablas no se puede inferir las relaciones. Que son atributos? atributos de que? como podemos saber si son uno a uno o uno a muchos o muchos a muchos si no sabemos que son? es importante saber las reglas de negocios para poder especificar una relacion.

Comment: Atributo de user y client, ejemplo atributo user : Numero telefonico, "321 231 231"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para aterrizar el ejercicio, pensemos que los User son ejecutivos de un banco, que tienen una cartera de clientes.

**Relación User-Client**

Para relacionar User con Client necesitas una tabla intermedia `user_client` con campos `(id, client_id, user_id)`.

Cada cliente sólo puede tener un ejecutivo, y un ejecutivo puede manejar muchos clientes. Por lo mismo:

En esa tabla el campo `client_id` debiese ser una llave única

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX client_id_idx ON user_client USING btree (client_id);
```

Cada registro en esa tabla debe corresponder a un cliente del banco. No puede tener un registro de un cliente que no existe, y debe eliminar la relación si un cliente deja el banco:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT client_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (client_id) 
REFERENCES client(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Un cliente sólo puede tener un ejecutivo, pero también puede *no tener ejecutivo asignado*. Por ejemplo si un ejecutivo deja el banco los clientes quedan sin ejecutivo, pero no dejan de ser clientes del banco.

```
ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Esos clientes quedan a la espera de asociarse a un nuevo ejecutivo.

**Relación User-Atributo y Cliente-Atributo**

Dices que la tabla es Atributo(id,Nombre,Valor). Pero esto no tiene sentido, no es tercera forma normal. Nos estás diciendo que la tabla dice algo como:

```
   id  |  nombre  | valor
 -------------------------
    1  |  pelo    | negro
    2  |  pelo    | rubio
    3  |  pelo    | pelirojo
    4  |  genero  | hombre
    5  |  genero  | mujer
```

Eso de por sí ya es raro, pero en fin, supongamos que cada tupla de Atributo identifica una combinación única de atributo-valor.

Ahora pensemos que hay una tabla que relaciona a una persona con un atributo (persona_atributo) tal que puedas listar en alguna parte que un cliente tiene el pelo rubio o una ejecutiva del banco es mujer.

Para mantener la integridad relacional, la tabla que puentea a una persona y un atributo debe referirse a una persona existente y asociarla con un atributo existente. Pero si acaso ese campo pudiera ser tanto el id de un User como el id de un Cliente. En tu enunciado no dicen si acaso es válido que tanto los User como los Client vengan de una tabla padre Persona. En caso contrario, es mejor usar una tabla puente para ambos casos.

Tabla user_atributo(id, user_id, atributo_id)
Tabla client_atributo(id, cliente_id, atributo_id)

Si un ejecutivo o un cliente se van del banco, la relación desaparece, por lo tanto en ambos casos ocurre que la referencia a user_id o a client_id conlleva `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Por el contrario, no debieras poder eliminar el atributo 1 porque no quieres perder el color de pelo de un cliente o dejarlo calvo diciendo que su pelo es null. Por lo tanto:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT atributo_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (atributo_id) 
REFERENCES atributo(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

**Pero aquí viene el problema de tu enunciado**

Tal como está planteada la entidad Atributo, un cliente podría tener varios pelos de distintos colores. O varios géneros, o varias edades, etc. Depende mucho del tipo de atributo que quieras mapear. Para mí, el esquema está mal planteado, y en cambio debiera haber una tabla de atributos sin valores (sólo un id que identifique cada atributo posible para un user o cliente)

```
 id  |  nombre
---------------
  1  | pelo
  2  | genero
  3  | DNI/RUT/CNI
  4  | edad
```

y dos tablas que caractericen a un cliente y un usuario:

Tabla usuario_atributo( id  user_id  atributo_id  valor)

De manera que se viera algo como:

```
 id   |  user_id  | atributo_id  | valor
------------------------------------
 1    | 1         |     1        | negro
 2    | 1         |     2        | mujer
 3    | 1         |     3        | 15.192.334-E
 4    | 1         |     4        | 45
```

Si esta tabla tuviera una llave única sobre (user_id, atributo_id) se garantizaría que un usuario no tenga dos colores de pelo. Las dos restricciones de más arriba se mantienen: el usuario debe existir, el atributo debe existir, eliminar un usuario elimina la relación, eliminar un atributo tira un error si un usuario ya está asociado a ese atributo.

Lo único que no me gusta de este planteamiento es que un usuario podría tener pelo *rojo* y otro *pelirrojo*. Uno podría tener género *hombre* y otro *masculino*.

No habría una lista de posibles valores de entre los cuales elegir. Pero eso ya de verdad es ponerse muy elaborado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al final termine modelando una tabla puente como la que describiste en tu respuesta, este tipo de esquema se llama modelo EAV ?

Comment: Un ultima cosa, la tabla puente usuario_atributo, lo ideal es que cada record tenga un id propio? Pues la tabla puente que e creado no tiene llave primaria, había pensado poner de llave primaria las  columnas user_id y atributo_id.

Comment: Se puede hacer asi, yo en lo personal prefiero una llave primaria serial y añadir una llave compuesta única si es necesario. Llaves primarias compuestas así como FK compuestas me ensucian el dibujo mental del esquema